# Recurrence involving square root

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

The recurrence equation I have is:
$$
T_n = c_1 + T_{n-1} + 2\sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_{n-1}}
$$
$$
T_0 = a
$$
$c_1,c_2,a$ are positive real numbers

I need to somehow convert this into a linear homogeneous recurrence or find a closed form if possible.

I tried backward substitution and after a few steps I gave up as it got too complex. I also looked up a few such questions (involving square root) here and tried all the tricks that I came across, taking $S_n = \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_n}$ and what not but that didn't seem to help.

An alternate form I came up with (didn't really help though):
$$
T_n = n * c_1 + T_1 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{f(T_i})
$$
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 x}
$$

And there is another form of the above recurrence which does not have any square roots but I found it impossible to make $T_n$ the subject of formula. I will post that too if needed.

I'd be grateful if someone helped me with this.

Comment: Try again with $S_n = \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_n}$. That works.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried that. I am getting a $S_{n-1}^2$ term too. I am looking for a linear equation. How do I get rid of that term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from the recurrence

$$T_n = c_1 + T_{n-1} + 2\sqrt{c_2 + c_1T_{n-1}}.$$

Multiplying that with $c_1$ - that is legitimate since $c_1 > 0$ - and adding $c_2$ yields

\begin{align}
c_2 + c_1 T_n &= c_2 + c_1^2 + c_1 T_{n-1} + 2c_1 \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_{n-1}}\\
&= c_1^2 + 2c_1\sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_{n-1}} + (c_2 + c_1 T_{n-1})\\
&= (c_1 + \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_{n-1}})^2.
\end{align}

Setting $S_n = \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 T_{n}}$, that recurrence is

$$S_n^2 = (c_1 + S_{n-1})^2,$$

which, after taking square roots - no problem because everything is positive - becomes

$$S_n = c_1 + S_{n-1}.$$

With the initial value $S_0 = \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 a}$, we thus have

$$S_n = n\cdot c_1 + \sqrt{c_2 + c_1 a}.$$

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks a ton!